# Azure Websites vs Azure Cloud Service Web Role

Tags: azure, azure-web-roles, azure-web-app-service

How is Azure Websites different from Azure Cloud Service Web Role when ASP.NET MVC is chosen to develop the Web Application?
Few differences are like:

1. Azure Websites can not be deployed using Cloud Service Packages
   while Web Role has to use it.
2. Creating Azure Websites takes much lesser time than Cloud Service
   Web Role.(I guess this is due to the setup of VM in case of Cloud
   Service Web Role)

Any more to add?

Comment: How about having dedicated VMs with cloud services?

Comment: May be this link will help: http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/services/web-sites/choose-web-app-service/